# Merge multiple rows to one row in a csv file using python pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file with multiple rows as stated below

```
Id  Name  Marks1 Marks2 Marks3 Marks4 Marks5
1   ABC   10     NAN    NAN    NAN    NAN
2   BCD   15     NAN    NAN    NAN    NAN
3   CDE   17     NAN    NAN    NAN    NAN
1   ABC   NAN    18     NAN    17     NAN
2   BCD   NAN    10     NAN    15     NAN
1   ABC   NAN    NAN    16     NAN    NAN
3   CDE   NAN    NAN    19     NAN    NAN
```

I want to merge the rows having the same id and name into a single row using pandas in python. The output should be :

```
Id  Name  Marks1 Marks2 Marks3 Marks4 Marks5
1   ABC   10     18     16     17     NAN
2   BCD   15     10     NAN    15     NAN
3   CDE   17     NAN    19     NAN    NAN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + `as_index=False` with [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) to eliminate `NaN`.

```
#df = df.replace('NAN',np.nan) #If necessary
df.groupby(['Id','Name'],as_index=False).first()
```

if you think it could have a pair Id Name with non-null values ​​in some column you could use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`Series.bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.bfill.html) + [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) to keep all the information.

```
df.groupby(['Id','Name']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
```

**Output**

```
   Id Name Marks1 Marks2 Marks3 Marks4  Marks5
0   1  ABC     10     18     16     17     NaN
1   2  BCD     15     10    NaN     15     NaN
2   3  CDE     17    NaN     19    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Hacky answer:

```
pd.groupby(“Name”).mean().reset_index()
```

This will only work if for each column there is only one valid value for each Name.